# Mysql Fetch entire row where value is max

Tags: mysql

I'm trying the following

```
Table : teams_members

Id          Team_id          User_id

1           103              65524
14          103              65529
16          103              65530
17          103              65526
19          103              65528

Table : users
Id          username

65524       Kaiprioska
65526       Darkstarling 
65528       Metazoans98
65529       Darth Laser
65530       TheBourbonKid

Table : users_playeraccounts
Id       user_id      summoner_name         rank_solo

7        65524        kaiprioska            19 
8        65524        swaggapandaa          14
9        65524        Yolonese Prophet      12
10       65529        Darth Laser           15
11       65530        TheBourbonkid         18
12       65528        Metazoans98           9
13       65530        TheBourbonKid         12
```

What the result needs to be :

```
user_id  summoner_name    rank_solo

65524    kaiprioska       19
65529    Darth laser      15
65530    TheBourbonkid    18
65528    metazoans98      9
655529   darth laser      15
```

So every teammember I need the users_playeraccounts entry where rank_solo is max for that user_id. I can get the full list so every playeraccount for every member but not the max entry.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_id, summoner_name, max(rank_solo ) as rank_solo
    from users_playeraccounts
    group by user_id
```

Comment: The `summoner_name` chosen for the result will indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT USER_ID, SUMMONER_NAME, MAX(RANK_SOLO) FROM users_playeraccounts GROUP BY USER_ID
```

Comment: The `summoner_name` chosen for the result will indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to query the table twice; once to get the highest ranks, and another to retrieve the records of them. (As an aside, if the user has two at highest rank, both with be in the results.)

```
SELECT q.user_id, q.summoner_name, q.rank_solo 
FROM (
   SELECT user_id, MAX(rank_solo) AS rank_solo
   FROM users_playeraccounts 
   GROUP BY user_id
) As maxQ
INNER JOIN users_playeraccounts AS q USING (user_id, rank_solo)
GROUP BY q.user_id -- If you only want one per user.
;
```

Comment: You sir are a genius. Many thanks for that. Is there a way to limit the result to 1 entry if multiple same ranks?

Comment: @battlenub see `GROUP BY` I just added at end of query.

Comment: @battlenub If you wanted all names, but only one row per user, you could change `q.summoner_name` to `GROUP_CONCAT(q.summoner_name) AS summoner_names`.

Comment: Nope just the summoner name + rank combo per user where rank was max!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT u.id, u.username, solo_rank FROM (
    SELECT [user_id] userID, MAX(rank_solo) solo_rank FROM users_playeraccounts GROUP BY [user_id]
) BestSoloRanking
JOIN users u ON BestSoloRanking.userID = u.id